# Display pst or universal time with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am trying to display time for a timestamp with javascript by converting it yo local time. How can I add pst or ut next to time with javascript or jquery with out other libraries?

```
function formatTimeStamp(timeStamp) {
    var localDate = new Date(timeStamp).toLocaleTimeString();
    return localDate;
}
```

‎Returns 11‎:‎03‎:‎28‎ ‎AM

I am trying to display as

‎11‎:‎03‎:‎28‎ ‎AM PST

Answer (score 2):

Use options:

```
.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB',{ timeZoneName: 'short' });
```

More here: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).

Comment: For the specific format they're asking for, I think the appropriate locale would be `en-US`, as `en-GB` returns 24h time as opposed to 12h time with AM/PM.